# Rails: Creating a method to save to a database column dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

User.rb

```
   def save_to_db(column_name)
      column = (column_name + "_data")
      self.column = "blah blah blah"
   end
```

e.g.

if I called save_to_db("stripe"), my intention would be to save "blah blah blah" to the user.stripe_data column.

But I'm having trouble converting the string into a method that I can call on self to save to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your request correctly, you can use the `[]=` method

```
def save_to_db(column_name)
  self["#{column_name}_data"] = "blah blah blah"
end
```

or use `send`.

```
def save_to_db(column_name)
  self.send("#{column_name}_data=", "blah blah blah")
end
```

Another approach that bypasses setters is to use `write_attribute` directly. But you can use this method only inside the model itself.

```
def save_to_db(column_name)
  self.write_attribute("#{column_name}_data", "blah blah blah")
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much